# Проблема бесполезных(нераскрытых) меток

Tags: обсуждение, метки

В любом SO перейдя в раздел `метки` и выбрав страницу с большим номером можно открыть иной мир. К примеру на ruSO увидел метку [`rl`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rl) с которой есть целый один вопрос и исходя из названия которой сразу ничего не понять, а данную метку отслеживают невообразимые 0 пользователей. ИМХО эту метку нужно удалить так как полно других поясняющих меток, или заменить на что то такое:

[`rl-learning`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rl)

Так же очень интересной можно назвать метку [`reacjs`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reacjs) :)

> Метка — это ключевое слово, позволяющее отнести ваш вопрос в одну категорию с другими похожими вопросами. Благодаря подбору правильных меток другие участники смогут проще найти ваш вопрос и быстрее дать на него ответ.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140385/discussion-on-question-by-daya---).